# Indexing a PCollection in DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've built a `PCollection` in Cloud Dataflow that I will write to disk as it is. I would like to build another collection that references items in the first collection by their index.  e.g.

PC1:

```
strings go here
some other string here
more strings
```

PC2:

```
0,1
1,1
0,2
```

I'm unsure how to get the indices in PC1 without writing the whole pipeline and starting another, and even then I'm not sure how to keep record of the line/record number being read. Is it safe to simply use a static variable? I would assume not based on the generally parallel nature of the platform.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're planning to do with the indexed collection? Perhaps it can be accomplished by simply generating a unique ID, rather than specifically a dense numeric ID in the range 0..N?

Comment: (generating a dense numeric ID is possible too, but more computationally intensive and possibly unnecessary - which is why I ask)

Comment: I'm going to write them to files. The system for which I am building this data needs two files: one is a text file with a record on each line, the other is pairs of integers that represent the line numbers of records in the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PCollection`'s are inherently unordered, so there's no such thing as "index of an item in a collection" - however, you can include the line number in the element itself: have `PC1` be a `PCollection<KV<Integer, String>>` where the Integer is the line number - basically read lines from a text file paired with their line number.

We currently don't provide a built-in source that does this - your best bet would be to write a simple `DoFn<String, KV<Integer, String>>` that takes the filename as input and uses `IOChannelFactory` to open the file and read it line by line and emit the contents with line numbers to produce `PC1`.